# How can I upload only the file in input type file without sending the entire form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, file

I'm writing a survey and I have a form with lot of inputs. The first ten are for personal data like and images, the others, in variable number, will be the questions of my survey.

I want the user to upload multiple images, but I'd like he could even remove some images right before. I know I can't remove files from the *file* object, so I had this idea: if I could upload the image right in the moment the user chooses (the *on input* event, or maybe *on load*) **without** sending the form I will store the image in a temporary folder (and with a js function I'll handle the file inputs to replace with a new one etc.).

So, finally, the question is: is there a way to upload a single input, maybe with ajax, without sending all inputs?

Comment: yes - you can use AJAX.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that I cant remember which methods to use. If I use form.submit(), even if is in another page, this will send the entire form, right?

Comment: yes - using `form.submit()` will submit the entire form. Perhaps adding your HTML markup would be a good idea?

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't paste the html, but is very dirty and some parts are generated dinamically, so it would be very messy. Anyway, I noticed that the $_FILES array is filled with the image data even if I don't send the form. This give me the opportunity to handle the file without sending data, I just use AJAX to start a php script in the same page. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax like this

```
   let formData = new FormData()
    var d = $('#fileid')[0].files[0] // field name 

    formData.append('fileid', d);
    formData.append('inputname', value);

    $.ajax({
        url: '/yourroute',
        method: 'POST',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        success: function(res){
            console.log('successfully')
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log('error')
        }
    })
```